# Can I revert back matlab-support installation?

Tags: software-installation, matlab, budgie

After installing MATLAB on Budgie I didn't get any launch icon so I opted for the terminal, after a while I decided to do something about it and went for the shortest path possible: I installed matlab-support (using the terminal). In the process I changed some file extensions because the installation recommended to do so, but after openning MATLAB (from the new icon) I stumbled upon this message:

```
com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: X11GLXDrawableFactory - Could not initialize shared resources for X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner false, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x2f42f193, isOwner false, <6812f351, 7716c644>[count 0, qsz 0, owner <NULL>]]]
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:326)
    at jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run(SharedResourceRunner.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:688)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:580)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:297)
    ... 2 more
```

And now live scripts don't work for me (luckily I can still use normal MATLAB code).

What options do I have? Can I just delete matlab-support? Or do I have to reinstall MATLAB?

EDIT: When I type
`lspci -k | grep -iE "VGA|video|3d|graphics" -A2` it shows the next lines:

```
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

And `vainfo` gets:

```
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 20.1.1 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Comment: That is a question for the people that make that software.

Comment: What video card do you have? Which video driver do you use? Please add the output of `lspci -k | grep -iE "VGA|video|3d|graphics" -A2` and `vainfo` (install it first by `sudo apt-get install vainfo`) to the question body by editing it.

Comment: @N0rbert Done. Hope the info helps.

Comment: So you have hybrid graphics. Maybe running MATLAB with `optirun matlab -desktop` will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply remove matlab-support package by

```
sudo apt-get remove matlab-support
```

Also you may want to know that [this package](/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop) is not a magic bullet, it is just a desktop-file with `matlab -desktop` Exec line inside and mex-helper.

Problems with OpenGL are probably unrelated with the above package.

Comment: I removed the package but when I open MATLAB it still shows the same message on the program command window as it did before. Funny thing is that the terminal shows this other message when I close MATLAB:

 `X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: true, open (no close attempt): 1/1, reusable (open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 1)
X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 1
X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x7f0960003b10, refCount 1, unCloseable false]`

Comment: I typed opengl software on matlab command window and now it's back to normal. I still don't feel quite comfortable with the fact that I can't run graphics using hardware. I also tried installing bumblebee but had some problems with the repositories. Anyway, thanks!